# JS Tree: Change Icon using CSS not accepting the base64 image code

Tags: html, css, background, base64

I am trying to change the icons in the JS tree. While giving the icons as png link in the CSS background property it is working. Following is the CSS used.

```
    li.jstree-open > .jstree-icon { background:url("http://jstree.com/tree-icon.png") 0px 0px no-repeat !important; 
} //Working

li.jstree-closed > .jstree-icon { background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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") !important;
background-position: 0px 0px !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important; 
} //not working
```

The data code is for fa-angle-up icon which I got from one online conversion site, http://fatopng.com/fontawesome-to-base64

The complete code example is in code pen, https://codepen.io/JGSpark/pen/XGEZRe

I am not sure why it is not applying the style in one case and not in the other.

Could anyone please figure it out? I am checking this for more than 2 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove > from the css like:

`li.jstree-closed .jstree-icon { background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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") !important;`

Comment: Is this working for you just by removing that > ? could you please share me the code pen link?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just noticed you added `background-size: 100%` Which solved my problem.